# Since Alcubierre drive moves a flat region of space, does it mean that space acts lika a liquid?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, warp-drives

The Alcubierre drive would move a patch of flat space through space and, leaving exotic matter aside, is mathematically correct. Does that means that space-time is not a "solid" lattice i.e. not attached to the surrounding space? (I'm biased by the usual spacetime lattice analogy).

I'm not interest if the Alcubierre drive is Physically possible or not: my interest is about the nature of spacetime.

Comment: Leaving the non-existence of negative tempearure baths aside I am a trillion aire who made his money with free-energy power plants. Lucky me that we get to play a game of "pretend" on this question. :-). To put it another way: you can't learn anything about nature by pretending that it works differently from how it actually does. Nobody ever said that spacetime was some sort of lattice, by the way. That's not even remotely consistent with Lorentz symmetry.

Comment: @Drakyoko: spacetime has dynamical responses to physical conditions, and thus has physical properties.  However, there are currently no accepted theories about "what it is"; the best you will find are analogies.  It certainly is neither a solid nor a liquid, nor is it a rubber sheet.  We can, however, say a few things about how it acts: curvature due to mass-energy concentrations, and cosmic expansion.  If you take a few courses in differential geometry and general relativity you can even do all of the math, but this doesn't tell you much more. See Misner, Thorne and Wheeler's "Gravitation".

Comment: The "surrouding space"???!?!?!

Comment: @WillO Well, as I said, I'm biased by the spacetime lattice analogy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no empirical or theoretical evidence of a surrounding space to be attached (or not attached) to.

And its not objective that the Alcubierre metric
"moves" a patch of flat space. There is **a** coordinate system that could describe it that way, but no coordinate system is more valid than another, and other coordinate systems would not describe it that way.

It's a bit like saying thing A is to the right of thing B. It's not like it's wrong so much as almost meaningless. A different perspective would disagree. But that's simply because left/right isn't an objective thing. People disagree but it isn't something that matters.

What makes is if from one perspective somethibg was to the left a certain amount and something else was further to the left a certain amount and then later those distances changed. That kind of thing is objective becasue the person that thinks they are to the right can agree about the distances.

In relativity, fewer things are objective. In fact thise distances turns out afent objective either.

Spacetime is a manifold with enough 4d points in it that you can separate different physical events that are separated by time and/or space by assigning the event different 4d points on the 4d manifold. In fact the 4d points in the 4d manifold are usually called events.

So you just need enough 4d points to assign different 4d points to different events. And then you need a topology to keep track what is close. And then you need a metric tensor to make it so the 4d curves between two events correctly measure the metric tensor along those curves to match up what a clock or a tape measure would measure along that curve.

Finally, you can have other tensor fields besides the metric tensor. That's it. There isn't anything else. Not a single other thing.